# Implementing a quad tree into an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, quadtree

Instead of using a binary tree, how can we store a quad-tree into an array. In a binary tree we store it into an array by numbering the nodes from 1-n, but how can we store a quad tree (each node has up to four children) into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system you could use is essentially the same as for binary trees. Let's say that the children of a node have a certain location, much like in a binary tree a child is either "left" or "right". For a quad-tree that could be "farleft", "midleft", "midright", "farright". The name doesn't really matter, just that there is an order and a node could have only the "midleft" and "farright" children, for instance.

So then iterate the levels of the tree from top to bottom, filling in the gaps with "blank" placeholders.

Here is an example tree:

[image]

The tiny edges indicate which children are "missing".

This tree has the following levels (hyphens where children are missing)

- Level 1: `d`
- Level 2: `kzne`
- Level 3: `r-s-----qt------`
- Level 4: `-ai--u--f-------`

Note that there are no placeholders for children of "missing" children, so, for example, level 4 has no hyphens that somehow relate to the z or e nodes. This is the same principle as for binary trees.

This can be concatenated to one string, and the trailing hyphens can be omited:

```
dkzner-s-----qt-------ai--u--f
```

This can be encoded as an array. For instance in JSON notation:

```
["d", "k", "z", "n", "e", "r", null, "s", null, null, null, null, null, 
 "q", "t", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "a", "i", null, null, 
 "u", null, null, "f"]
```

There is no ambiguity on how this can be turned back into the same tree. It is essentially the same system as for encoding binary trees in an array.

Answer (score 0):

For binary tree, the algo boils down to O(n-1/2). For a "quad tree," which has 4 children, try O(n-1/4).